# Pull-To-Refresh, but instead of refreshing, bring a new page on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, pull-to-refresh

I'm new to `flutter` and I'd like to know if it's possible in a `ListView` that when the user reaches the bottom, a `pull-to-refresh` is enabled, which redirects to another page already (with `Navigator`).

I want an effect similar like [this](https://dribbble.com/shots/11304885-Browse-Photos-Interaction).

But under a `ListView` (the user needs to reach the bottom) and then swipe again to push another page, with a `effect` like the link above.

It would be possible? I tried used `NotificationListener`, Scrollable `Controller`, and nothing happened.

**The specific effect I want is when the user reaches the bottom, it has a 'pull to refresh' effect like Twitter (where you swipe up (hold), a text appears, and when you realise the finger, the page updates, where in my app, it brings another page)**

I tried something with 'Gesture Detector' on a card at the bottom - and it kinda works, but I don't have the animation of swiping holding and releasing the finger.

Let me know if i can clarify this question more. Thanks

Comment: You can achieve that using a ViewPager with a vertical orientation

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla thanks, I think that helps, but i'll edit my answer with more details

Answer (score 0):

Use [PageView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html) like so:

```js
PageView(
  children: <Widget>[
    // Add children here
  ],
  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried something similar - edited my question with more details - but i want a effect pull to refresh like (where you can swipe - hold and release the finger). Do you know can it be achieved? Refresh Indicator doesn't work in this case, i think